# Third monitor not detected Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg, display

Afer upgrading something by software updater i got my 3 monitors blacked out

Then after hard reboot i got only one monitor working

After changing the videocard's drivers to Nouveau display driver from xserver-xord-video-nouveau, my 2 last monitors started working, but the first one didn't

My videocard is gefroce gtx980

My 3 monitors is fully working on this pc but on the WINDOWS OS. Before the update they were working correctly at the same time

Here is Xrandr output

```
    Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 3200 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected 1280x1024+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 380mm x 300mm
   1280x1024     59.89*+
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
XWAYLAND1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 520mm x 290mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77
```

The commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge 'nvidia*'
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
```

Doesn't help they turn off Monitors num 2 and 3, but turn on monitor num 1 (after reboot of course)

I also use adapter for my monitors for 1 it's dvi-display port, for second vga-dvi and for third dvi - hdmi. I tried swapping adapters, that did not help

Answer (score 0):

A recent update to my 22.04.3 LTS system seems to have disabled a monitor on my two monitor system as well.  I have two identical monitors, one hooked to an Nvidia Quadro P620 card, one to the Intel UHD630 on the system board of my ASUS PB60G.

A few days ago the system upgraded Wayland and xserver-xorg-legacy.  Right after that the monitor on the P620 stopped working.

After checking the monitor, cables, adapters, etc, I thought maybe the P620 died.

Figuring I had nothing to lose I went to Settings > About > Software Update > Additional Drivers and changed over from using the X.org xserver Nouveau driver to the Nvidia 535 driver.  I selected that driver radio button and clicked Apply and watched the "installing" progress bar. After rebooting, the monitor on the P620 starting working again.

The About screen now says the Windowing System is X11 and not Wayland.  Not sure if there are any repercussions from that, since I have not checked everything on the system.